# Java JDBC PreparedStatement Foreign Key Constraint Failed

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm designing a billing program with SQLite and JDBC, and I'm trying to use this helper method:

```
public static void preparedInsert(String query, String[] inserters) {
    Connection c = connect();
    try {
        PreparedStatement statement = c.prepareStatement(query);

        for (int i = 0; i < inserters.length; i++) {
            statement.setObject(i + 1, "\'" + inserters[i] + "\'");
        }
        statement.executeUpdate();
        c.commit();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database updated!");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error updating database: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    disconnect(c);
}

public static Connection connect() {
    Connection c = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();  
        config.enforceForeignKeys(true);  
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:MRWBilling.db", config.toProperties());
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error connecting to database: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return c;
}

public static void disconnect(Connection c) {
    try {
        c.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error disconnecting from database: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The parameter I'm trying to pass in is this:

```
SQLiteJDBC.preparedInsert("insert into timesheets(date, attorney, notes) values(?, ?, ?);", 
            new String[]{date, attorneyName, notes});
```

Timesheets has four rows: id, date, attorney and notes where id is set to autoincrement and where attorney is a foreign key to the attorney table.  The attorneyName I'm passing in actually exists in the attorney's table.

This was working fine during a prior build when I was using regular statements, but now that I've swapped to prepared statements, I'm getting this:

```
Error updating database: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT] Abort due to constraint violation (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed)
```

I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional single quotes that are wrapping the parameters are probably causing the FK violation. Use this instead in your loop:

`statement.setString(i+1, inserters[i]);`

You may also need to remove the semicolon from the `insert` statement.

Comment: I can't believe that mattered?  But it did -- thanks, man.  I guess I feel a little foolish -- this thing was driving me crazy.

Comment: Yes, that's because you were trying to insert a value _with the quotes_ (e.g. `'Matlock'` instead of `Matlock`). Nice to hear it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Lee,

Can you try removing semicoln in the end like the one below
"insert into timesheets(date, attorney, notes) values(?, ?, ?)"

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I removed the semicolon and nothing different happened.  I feel like it's optional?

Comment: Its optional but some times non-standard jdbc drivers fail to parse SQL having semicoln.

Answer (score 0):

Also verify if the attorneyName is exactly same as in attorney's table, some times we forget case sensitivity

Comment: Thanks again.  Yes, it's exactly the same.  All this was working when I was using regular statements instead of prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your preparedInsert method seems to be creating the problem. try altering it like below

PreparedStatement statement = c.prepareStatement(query);

```
    for (int i = 0; i < inserters.length; i++) {
        statement.setString(i + 1, inserters[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks -- this is the same solution Mick provided above.  I appreciate your help.